# Problema: "Funcion en ngFor se ejecuta multiple veces sin parar"

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, angular4

**HTML:**

```
<input #inputCodigo type="text" (keyup)="searchProductoBarCode($event)">
  </div>
</article>
<article *ngIf="proforma && proforma.productos.length">
  <table #tableDispatch tabindex="-1" [attr.role]="role-table" appScrolling [data]="productosDespachados"
         (selected)="productoSelected=$event">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Fracción</th>
      <th>P.unitario</th>
      <th>P.total</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of productosDespachados; let i=index" [class.selected]="onSelected(p,i)">
      <td>{{ p.prod_codigo }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.prod_descripcion }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyDownInput($event,i)" #inputsCantidad></td>
      <td>{{ p.prec_vta_final }}</td>
      <td>{{ getPrecioFinalv2() }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.prod_stock_cantidad }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Función `onSelected()`, se repite múltiples veces sin parar, y hace lenta mi aplicación, la función `onSelected()`, devuelve true o false según sea el caso:

```
onSelected(producto, index) {
const result = Object.is(producto, this.productoSelected);
if (result) {
  this.inputsFraccion.toArray()[index].nativeElement.focus();
  }
    return Object.is(producto, this.productoSelected);
}
```

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco más que quieres hacer? Así te puedo dar una mejor respuesta

Comment: la funcion onSelected, siempre se ejecuta, te muestro una imagen: https://ibb.co/gCDjgm

Comment: Si, lo entiendo y también entiendo porque pasa. Te consulto bien que deseas hacer para darte una mejor respuesta, ya que hay otros errores conceptuales también.

Comment: A bueno, simplemente que cuando ese objeto sea seleccionado, en ese mismo instante, se haga focus al input que esta en ese <td><input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyDownInput($event,i)" #inputsCantidad></td>

Comment: El problema es que cuando hago eso, a cada rato se ejecuta el focus. Y no deja hacer focus en otro lado. Acotar que el sistema que estoy realizando es sin mouse, por eso siempre uso el teclado para todas las interacciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explicación

Esto te sucede porque:

`[class.xxx]` ( lo mismo ocurre con `[style.xxx.yy]`)son sintaxis especial de Angular donde:

> ```
> [class.my-class]="expresión"
> ```

Agrega (o quita) la clase de CSS "my-class" a (o desde) el elemento dependiendo de si los resultados de la expresión son `true` o `false`.

### **Problema:**

Lo que sucede es que cuando pones una función en esa expresión, se ejecuta reiteradas veces para comprobar si cambio ( en el mismo siclo que [`ngOnChange()`](https://victorroblesweb.es/2017/08/12/hooks-de-angular-4/) ). Para solucionar esto, asigna una variable booleana la cual tu manejas, entonces en cada ejecución de `ngOnChange()` solo comprobara si cambio el valor de dicha variable.

### Solución:

(alternativa a `onSelected(p,i)` y recomendación)

`(selected)="productoSelected=$event"` No es una buen practica, ya que te puede dar problemas al momento del `build --prod`, te recomiendo realizar una función que reciba `$event` y asigne su valor y aquí mismo podrías agregar el focus para tu input, con algo como lo siguiente:

```
const index = productosDespachados.indexOf(productoSelected);
this.inputsFraccion.toArray()[index].nativeElement.focus();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Federico, funciono!!!

Comment: Para complementar, mi funcion quedo asi: 
` code` onScrolling(productoSelected) {
    const index = this.productosDespachados.indexOf(productoSelected);
    if (this.inputsFraccion.toArray()[index]) {
      this.productoSelected = productoSelected;
      this.inputsFraccion.toArray()[index].nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

Comment: De nada, recuerda votar la pregunta si te funciono, te aporto conocimiento y te pareció correcta. Saludos.